# Cannot start a Virtual Device on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin-android-player

I wanted to do the simple [Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) available on the `Xamarin Developer` website but I faced an issue when I wanted to start a Virtual Device, indeed when I try to execute my project on any version of Nexus 4, 5 or 10, it starts and stops immediately the Device.

According to the log file the errors are following:

```
WindowServer[269]: 
    disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Xamarin Android Player" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
Xamarin Android Player[2760]: 
    warning: exception inside UnhandledException handler: The requested feature is not implemented.
```

I found [this forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55092/opengl-broken-after-last-update-6-5-1) in which they say that it works if they downgrade the version of `Xamarin Android Player` from `0.6.5` to `0.6.2` but it didn't work for me.

My configuration is the following:

- OSX El Capitain
- Xamarin Studio Community version 5.10.3
- Xamarin Android Player 0.6.5 (1)
- Virtual Box 5.0.18

For your information just in case it could help somehow:

1. I can start manually the factories from Virtual Box
2. I get the same behavior (start and immediate stop) that I have with the `Xamarin Studio` if I launch a Virtual Device directly from `Xamarin Android Player`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) works the same but I have found it to be more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to test it right now. But unfortunately I have to use Xamarin for my task anyway :-(

Comment: You have to Use Xamarin Android Player or you have to use Xamarin? GenyMotion is just an android emulator so you could use it for Xamarin development or native development if you are using it for personal use there is a free option https://www.genymotion.com/thank-you-freemium/

Comment: Yes it is what I've just realized, I could deploy my app on the virtual device of GenMotion. I'm just starting with Xamarin and Android that's why. I already up voted your answer now I mark it as best answer thank you very much

Comment: Ah no worries, theres alot of android emulators out there, some are slightly more reliable than others

Comment: hopefully otherwise I was pretty stuck because of this ugly bug :-)